# Android: enums with values which can be translated to other locales

Tags: android, enums, internationalization, locale

Suppose I have below `enum`:

```
public enum Feelings {
    happy("label1"),sad("label2")
    private final String name;
    private Feelings(String s) {
        name = s;
    }
    public boolean equalsName(String otherName) {
        return (otherName == null) ? false : name.equals(otherName);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

when I call its `.toString()` it returns labels defined for different enumeration. I use these labels on UI and they will be displayed to users.

When I consider to publish my app with different locales, It comes to my mindhow can I define these labels such that they can be translated to other languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the actual value of the label in the enum you could use the string resource id.

```
public enum Feelings {
  happy(R.string.happy_label), sad(R.string.sad_label);
  private final int strId;

  private Feelings(int strId) {
    this.strId = strId;
  }

  @StringRes public int getStringId() {
    return strId;
  }
}
```

This way Android will pick the correct translation of your strings given the device's locale

Your usage could then look like this:

```
textView.setText(Feelings.happy.getStringId());
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be much different than how you handle localization outside of an enum. Just need to pass in reference to Resources. So something like:

```
public enum Feelings {
    happy(R.string.happy),
    sad(R.string.sad)

    private final int nameId;

    private Feelings(int nameId) {
        this.nameId = nameId;
    }

    public String toString(Resources res) {
        return res.getString(nameId);
    }
}
```